# Take action when face detected (Android Camera2 API)

Tags: android, android-camera2

I need to hide the camera shooting button if no face has been detected.
I have been trying this for three days. I couldn't find a way to take action when face is detected.

Note: this code is working just fine I just need to add face detector how and where? And then use this face detector to take action on the camera shooting button

```java
btn_shot.setVisibility(view.GONE)
```

Here is creating the Camera preview:

```java
private void creatCameraPreview() throws CameraAccessException {
        SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimensions.getWidth(),
imageDimensions.getHeight());

        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                if (cameraDevice == null)
                    return;

                cameraCaptureSession = session;
                try {
                    updatePreview();
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                Toast.makeText(CameraTaken.this, "Configuration Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }, null);
    }
```

**Here is opening the Camera:**

```java
private void openCamera() throws CameraAccessException {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        assert manager != null;
        cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0]; //[0] for the back facing camera [1] for the front facing camera

        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);


        assert map != null;
        imageDimensions = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CameraTaken.this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 101);
            return;
        }
        manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallBack, null);




    }
```

Comment: It's not clear where you're having trouble.  Have you tried modifying the official sample apps instead of building it from scratch? https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2Basic

Comment: I am not having a problem with the current code (which is mentioned above). I am trying to add face detector, and if there is no face detected I need to set the button visibility to GONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the face detector in the camera API, available on most devices: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE to turn it on, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult#STATISTICS_FACES to read if any faces are detected.